# Empty form is getting sumitted in php/jquery

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I have written the following code using jquery and php to submit the form when user clicks on save button, the form is getting submitted successfully but the forma data is empty (post data)

This is what i am doing :

I am  checking  whether the save button is clicked, if so then i am  sending  a mail and setting the form action then submitting the form.

```
<form id= "contactform"  method='POST'>   
 .......
<input type='submit' name='submit_details' value=Save />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

function submit_form()
{
   $("#contactform").attr("action","https://functions.php"); 
   $("#contactform").submit() 
 }
```

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit_details']))
{

   mail("myself@gmail.com", $subject, $mailbody, $headers);
   echo "<script> submit_form(); </script>";
}

?>
```

but when i call the the javascript function directly, the form data will pass

```
<form id= "contactform" onsubmit='javascript:submit_form();' method='POST'>
```

So, what is the problem here.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't putting the action in the form element? Or why you are actually submitting versus using AJAX? It doesn't look like there is a lot in the functions.php.

Comment: The purpose of your code is not really clear...When you call the submit_form() action the form submits (it would do anyway, since you didn't provide a return false to stop the browser from doing a regular submit). What's the purpose of your echo in php?

Comment: is functions.php is same file which contains the form.

Comment: from where you are getting the values of mail variable is it coming from the post.

Comment: i found the solution, its here http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-submit.html

Answer (score 0):

Damien is correct...the below works though.

http://jsfiddle.net/D5Ldn/

```
<form id="contactform" method='POST'>

<input type='submit' name='submit_details' value=Save />
</form>

$('input[type="submit"]').click(function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
   $("#contactform").attr("action","https://functions.php"); 
   $("#contactform").submit();
 });
```

Comment: along with this, i have to send a mail when the "save" button is clicked

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I got what you need, basically you want:

1. a button that when is clicked sends an e-mail;
2. after this e-mail you want the whole form (which one I don't know. I assumed is the same and you just didn't write your input fields) to be submitted; 
   you might want to move this logic inside your PHP, since you're already doing the processing.

So, if the workflow is this one, you could try with:

HTML:

```
<form id="contactform" method="post" action="">
<!-- your other inputs go here? -->
<input type="text" name="input1" value="" />
<!-- I'm just guessing this ones.. -->
<input type="submit" name="submit_details" value="Salve" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
$('#contactform').submit(function({
    var dataString = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
      url: 'functions.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: dataString,
      success:function(response){
         alert(response);
      }
   });
   return false;
});
```

PHP functions.php

```
if($_POST['submit_details'])
{
    //now send email:
    if(mail("myself@gmail.com", $subject, $mailbody, $headers))
    {
      //mail sent: do the rest
      $input1 = isset($_POST['input1']) ? $_POST['input1'] : '';
      // and so on for the rest of the inputs.
      // do whatever you need to.
      return 'Mail sent and data saved!';
    }
    else
    {
      return 'Couldn\'t send mail!';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just change the button type to "button"

```
      <input type='button' name='submit_details' value=Save onclick="submit_form()" />
```